# How to develop recording app, which uses multi mics to record at once?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to develop an app in flutter which can record audio from multiple external mics, cannot  find anything.

Comment: Since that's likely to require highly platform specific development, which needs to be done in native code, perhaps Flutter isn't the right choice.

Comment: There would be a solution.